# only highlighting new parts added

Tags: latexdiff, changes

I am using latexdiff to compare two tex files, which highlights any changes (added or deleted) in the final PDF. Is there any way to only highlight the new parts added, and do not highlight the parts deleted?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Predefined styles

If you look in the [manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/support/latexdiff/doc/latexdiff-man.pdf) you will see that there are a few predefined styles that mark things up differently. These are `UNDERLINE`,  `CTRADITIONAL`,  `TRADITIONAL`,  `CFONT`, `FONTSTRIKE`, `INVISIBLE`,
`CHANGEBAR`, `CCHANGEBAR`, `CULINECHBAR` and `CFONTCBHBAR`. `UNDERLINE` is the default. To use e.g. the `TRADITIONAL` style, invoke `latexdiff` with

```
latexdiff --type=TRADITIONAL old.tex new.tex > diff.tex
```

It could be that one of them is more to your liking. If not, you have the option of using a custom preamble.

**Update**: In version 1.1.0 of `latexdiff` there is a new style called `BOLD` that may be what you're after. New text is typeset in bold, deleted text is simply removed. (I had version 1.0.4 installed, which does not have this style. Thanks to [frederik for mentioning it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251224/only-highlighting-new-parts-added/251241?noredirect=1#comment599084_251241).)

## Custom preamble

If you open a `.tex` file generated by `latexdiff`, you will see a section in the preamble that may look something like this:

```
%DIF LATEXDIFF DIFFERENCE FILE
%DIF DEL old.tex   Sat Jun 20 10:36:29 2015
%DIF ADD new.tex   Sat Jun 20 10:36:36 2015
%DIF PREAMBLE EXTENSION ADDED BY LATEXDIFF
%DIF UNDERLINE PREAMBLE %DIF PREAMBLE
\RequirePackage[normalem]{ulem} %DIF PREAMBLE
\RequirePackage{color}\definecolor{RED}{rgb}{1,0,0}\definecolor{BLUE}{rgb}{0,0,1} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFadd}[1]{{\protect\color{blue}\uwave{#1}}} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdel}[1]{{\protect\color{red}\sout{#1}}}                      %DIF PREAMBLE
%DIF SAFE PREAMBLE %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddbegin}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddend}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelbegin}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelend}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
%DIF FLOATSAFE PREAMBLE %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddFL}[1]{\DIFadd{#1}} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelFL}[1]{\DIFdel{#1}} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddbeginFL}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddendFL}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelbeginFL}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelendFL}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
%DIF END PREAMBLE EXTENSION ADDED BY LATEXDIFF
```

This block of code defines how the diffs are marked up. Particularly, the `\DIFdel` command is what defines the markup of deleted text:

```
\providecommand{\DIFdel}[1]{{\protect\color{red}\sout{#1}}}
```

You see that it is defined to be colored red, and striked out.

#### Using a custom preamble

Copy the `latexdiff` part of the preamble to a new file, and save this e.g. as `diffpreamble.tex`. Then modify the above commands to your liking. If you want deleted parts to be simply removed, modify the `\DIFdel` command to

```
\providecommand{\DIFdel}[1]{}
```

Finally, when invoking `latexdiff`, tell it to use this preamble file with

```
latexdiff --preamble=diffpreamble.tex old.tex new.tex > diff.tex
```

#### Example

With `old.tex` as

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

This is some text.

\end{document}
```

and `new.tex` as

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

This is some stuff.
And more.

\end{document}
```

`latexdiff --preamble=diffpreamble.tex old.tex new.tex > diff.tex` with the above suggested modification gives this output:

[image]

Comment: Markupstyle BOLD (from version 1.1.0 onwards) does just as asked in the question. Use as described above

Comment: Is it also possible to change the color from blue to red and remove the underline?

Comment: @alper Just looking at my own answer, `\providecommand{\DIFadd}[1]{{\protect\color{blue}\uwave{#1}}}` seems to define the formatting for added text, so modify that to `\providecommand{\DIFadd}[1]{{\protect\color{red}#1}}`. Untested.

Answer (score 0):

For me this one works on linux:

You first create a tex file '\providecommand{\DIFdel}[1]{}' by:

```
echo \\providecommand{\\DIFdel}[1]{} > diff.tex
```

Then you add the result of latexdiff to that file by:

```
latexdiff old.tex new.tex >> diff.tex
```